# Can not Upload images and pdf together with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to upload image file and pdf data, I find it difficult because the extension in different I have made simplified but the data does not go into the folder in the show..

```
function add_module_external(){
        $id_module = "9090909";
        $file_data = array();
        $image_data = array();

        $config_image["file_name"] = $id_module;
        $config_image["upload_path"] = "./assets/file/image-module/";
        $config_image["overwrite"] = TRUE;
        $config_image["allowed_types"] = "gif|jpg|png|";

        $this->load->library('upload', $config_image); 
        $this->upload->initialize($config_image);
        $upload_background = $this->upload->do_upload('other_image');
        if($upload_background){
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
            $image = $image_data['file_name'];
        }else{
            $image = $this->input->post('background');
        }


        // pdf and ppt upload       
        $config_file['file_name'] = $id_module;
        $config_file['upload_path'] = '/assets/file/materi-module/';
        $config_file['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config_file); 
        $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
        $upload_pdf = $this->upload->do_upload('pdf_data'); 

        if($upload_pdf){
                $file_data = $this->upload->data();
                $content = $file_data["file_name"];         
            }else{
                $content = $this->input->post("text_data");
            }   


        $query = $this->my_module->new_module($image, $id_module, $content);
                redirect($this->agent->referrer());     

    }
```

Comment: you can't load a library twice. use initialize

Answer (score 1):

On the second time you are loading the upload library, it will be skipped because you already loaded the library, so the file config will still being loaded on the image upload.
What you could do :
1. Load the library using provided image config
2. Process image upload data
3. Initialize upload using file config
4. Process file upload data

```
function add_module_external(){
    $id_module = "9090909";
    $file_data = array();
    $image_data = array();

    $config_image["file_name"] = $id_module;
    $config_image["upload_path"] = "./assets/file/image-module/";
    $config_image["overwrite"] = TRUE;
    $config_image["allowed_types"] = "gif|jpg|png|";

    $this->load->library('upload', $config_image); 
    $upload_background = $this->upload->do_upload('other_image');
    if($upload_background){
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
        $image = $image_data['file_name'];
    }else{
        $image = $this->input->post('background');
    }


    // pdf and ppt upload       
    $config_file['file_name'] = $id_module;
    $config_file['upload_path'] = '/assets/file/materi-module/';
    $config_file['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config_file['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $this->upload->initialize($config_file);
    $upload_pdf = $this->upload->do_upload('pdf_data'); 

    if($upload_pdf){
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $content = $file_data["file_name"];         
        }else{
            $content = $this->input->post("text_data");
        }   


    $query = $this->my_module->new_module($image, $id_module, $content);
            redirect($this->agent->referrer());     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload jpg and pdf files together, but you can't rename the file name

Try this code.

```
if(!empty($_FILES["ktp"])) {
    if(!file_exists("./uploads/".$this->input->post('no_hp'))) {
        mkdir("./uploads/".$this->input->post('no_hp'));
    }
    $configktp['upload_path']          = './uploads/'.$this->input->post('no_hp')."/";
    $configktp['allowed_types']        = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $configktp);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ktp'))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }

}

if(!empty($_FILES["ijazah"])) {
    $configijazah['upload_path']          = './uploads/'.$this->input->post('no_hp')."/";
    $configijazah['allowed_types']        = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $configijazah);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('ijazah'))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
}

if(!empty($_FILES["cv"])) {
    $configpdf['upload_path']          = './uploads/'.$this->input->post('no_hp')."/";
    $configpdf['allowed_types']        = '*';
    $this->load->library('upload', $configpdf);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('cv'))
    {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    }
}
```